# Should I use tiles in a snake game?

Tags: java, libgdx, tiles, tilemap

I'm building a simple snake game, which is my first game ever. I'm using LibGDX, which is Java-based.

I've looked at the Tiled Map Editor, but I don't know if it is necessary in a simple game like snake. Is it?

I don't know how to make grid however, and I think that the map editor could make a grid easier than by code? I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you are overthinking. You could make a simple snake game even without sprites.
Why do you need a map editor for a snake game? It won't help you do your code.
If it is your first game start without Tiled.
I think you have a concrete idea how you want to make it but I would suggest to look after some tutorials to compare if you are on the right track.

I think it also may help if you understand that representation of the data (rendering) and the data itself are mostly two different things.

Your snake game will probably consist of the background, which could be a solid color, a big image or a map of tiles and your snake for which you probably need 2 sprites (head and tail) which you then can rotate.
Alternatively you can use a tile map but I would not advice to start with it because then you narrow your solutions to problems you may stumble across to a strict grid and for a beginner I would advise some more "artistic freedom".